# Ignore spaces in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

For my search I want to take into account the fact that the `"space"` character is not mandatory in a filter request.
For exemple:
when I filter on `"THE ONE"` I see the corresponding document.
I want to see it even if I write `"THEONE"`.
This is how my query is built today:

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
     .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("description", "*" + 
         searchedWord.toLowerCase() + "*"))
     .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("id", "*" + 
         searchedWord.toUpperCase() + "*"))
     .should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("label", "*" + 
         searchedWord.toUpperCase() + "*"))
     .minimumShouldMatch("1"));
```

What I want is to add this filter: ([Writing a space-ignoring autocompleter with ElasticSearch](https://medium.com/@davedash/writing-a-space-ignoring-autocompleter-with-elasticsearch-6c3c28e3a974))

```
"word_joiner": {
  "type": "word_delimiter",
  "catenate_all": true
}
```

But I don't know how to do this using the API.
Any idea?
Thanks!
**EDIT**: Following @raam86 suggestion, I added my own custom analyzer:

```
{
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "word_joiner": {
            "type": "word_delimiter",
            "catenate_all": true
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "custom_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "word_joiner"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And here is the document:

```
@Document(indexName = "cake", type = "pa")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/config/settings.json")
public class PaElasticEntity implements Serializable {
   @Field(type = FieldType.String, analyzer = "custom_analyzer")
    private String maker;
}
```

Still not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [shingle token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html). Simple example.

**1. create index with settings**

```
PUT joinword
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "word_joiner": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "output_unigrams": "true",
                    "token_separator": ""
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "word_join_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "word_joiner"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. check that analyzer work as expected**

```
GET joinword/_analyze?pretty
{
  "analyzer": "word_join_analyzer",
  "text": "ONE TWO"
}
```

**output:**

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "one",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "onetwo",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "two",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

So now you can find this document by `one`, `two` or `onetwo`. A search will be case insensitive.

#### Working Spring example

Full project [available on GitHub](https://github.com/nikita-klimov/spring-es-shingle-filter-example).

**Entity:**

```
@Document(indexName = "document", type = "document", createIndex = false)
@Setting(settingPath = "elasticsearch/document_index_settings.json")
public class DocumentES {
    @Id()
    private String id;
    @Field(type = String, analyzer = "word_join_analyzer")
    private String title;

    public DocumentES() {
    }

    public DocumentES(java.lang.String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public java.lang.String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(java.lang.String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "DocumentES{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {ElasticsearchProperties.class})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(DocumentES.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(DocumentES.class);

        elasticsearchTemplate.index(new IndexQueryBuilder()
                .withIndexName("document")
                .withType("document")
                .withObject(new DocumentES("ONE TWO")).build()
        );

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices("document")
                .withTypes("document")
                .withQuery(matchQuery("title", "ONEtWO"))
                .build();

        List<DocumentES> result = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(query, DocumentES.class);

        result.forEach (System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still doesn't work with this analyzer :( But I couldn't do the step two... I just tried this query: `http://localhost:9200/cake/_search?q=ONETWO` and it doesn't give me any result. What tool do you use to preform the second step?

Comment: @anna  you can use `curl` something like `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/cake/_analyze?pretty -d {
  "analyzer": "word_join_analyzer",
  "text": "ONE TWO"
}`

Comment: All right, so I executed this `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/cake/_analyze?analyzer=word_join_analyzer&pretty" -d 'ONE TWO'` and I get the error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: TWO'`... Does it allow spaces? I tried using the character `%20`, but the results were totally wrong.

Comment: `curl localhost:9200/joinword/_analyze?pretty -d '{"analyzer":"word_join_analyzer", "text": "ONE TWO"}'`

Comment: Found solution: escaping space character as `"\ "`. So I get the right output! The one that is shown by @Nikita Klimov... So does this mean that this works?

Comment: @Anna yes, at output of `_analyze` endpoint you see terms by which you can search. In spring you can use simple MatchQueryBuilder to search for document. It will work. The main thing is not to forget to index the documents

Comment: @Anna, I've talked a little about elasticsearch internals at the response to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587293/spring-data-elastic-search-wild-card-search/45601064#45601064 . In my answer there are also examples for spring

Comment: @NikitaKlimov: Thanks! I am gonna take a look at it. But just for your previous comment, The code that I wrote above using `BoolQueryBuilder` should work as it is donc't you think?

Comment: @Anna wildcard queries is really bad practice, because they are too slow. Simple match query or even term query much better choice. But when you deal with term query it should not be forgotten that the request does not go through the analysis stage

Comment: @Anna I edited the comment and added a working example for spring

Comment: @NikitaKlimov: Thanks for all the explanation, I understand better. It works with with the code that you gave me :) But it's not the same behaviour as the wildcard queries... If I enter "netwo", I want to get "one two" as a result...

Comment: For this purpose you can use fuzziness. It will still be better than wildcard. Example `matchQuery("title", "ONEtWO").fuzziness(1)`.

Comment: @Anna besides fuzziness you can use n-gram analyzer and `@MultiField` for different tokenizer at the same time

Comment: The first analyzer that I put in my question worked very well when I added  `"tokenizer": "keyword" ` :) The problem now is that when I search for "one two" I don't find my document ^^

Comment: Same thing with the one that you proposed @NikitaKlimov

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Anna The problem is that you do not have clear requirements to search. Formulate them and I'll show you how to implement them

Comment: As for the initial question, I believe that I fully answered it. @Anna

Comment: Ok @NikitaKlimov :)