# Elasticsearch query to get results irrespective of spaces in search text

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to fetch data from Elasticsearch matching from a field **name**. I have following two records

```
{
  "_index": "sam_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "key",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Sample Name"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "_index": "sam_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "key1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Sample Name"
  }
}
```

When I try to search using texts like **sam, sample, Sa, etc,** I able fetch both records by using match_phrase_prefix query. The query I tried with match_phrase_prefix is

```
GET sam_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix" : {
      "name": "sample"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to fetch the records when I try to search with string **samplen**. I need search and get results irrespective of spaces between texts. How can I achieve this in Elasticsearch?

Comment: I think this is helpful to you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402504/ignore-spaces-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Do you want to match only using phrase prefix prefix or parts of the `name` field should also match ? E.g., does name `sample name foo` match `namef` or `amplename` ?

Comment: if you can show us the mapping you used? especially for the field `name` weather the field is defined `text` or `keyword`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand how Elasticsearch works and why it gives the result and doesn't give the result.

**ES works on the token match, Documents which you index in ES goes through the [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) process and creates and stores the tokens generated from this process to inverted index which is used for searching.**

Now when you make a query then that query also generates the search tokens, these can be as it is in the search query in case of term query or tokens based on the analyzer defined on the search field in case of match query. Hence it's very important to understand the internals of your search query.

Also, it's very important to understand the mapping of your index, **ES uses the standard analyzer by default on the text fields.**

You can use the [Explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API to understand the internals of the query like which search tokens are generated by your search query, how documents matched to it and on what basis score is calculated.

In your case, I created the name field as text, which uses the word joined analyzer explained in [Ignore spaces in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402504/ignore-spaces-in-elasticsearch) and I was able to get the document which consists of `sample name` when searched for `samplen`.

**Let us know if you also want to achieve the same and if it solves your issue.**