# elasticsearch php not return search result without space

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have added 15k records in elasticsearch index `products_idx1` and type `product`.

In records product name like `apple iphone 6` so when I search for `iphone6` it returns empty data.

Here is my code in php elasticsearch

```
<?php

    use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

   $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
 $values =['name','name.prefix','name.suffix','sku'];
$params =
[
'client'=>['verify'=>1,'connect_timeout'=>5],
'from'=> 0,
'size'=>25,
 'body'  =>[
'query' => [
 'bool'=>
            [
            'should'=> [[
                'multi_match'=> ['query'=>'iphone6','type'=>'cross_fields','fields'=>$values,'operator'=>'OR']
                ],
                ['match'=>['all'=>['query'=>'iphone6','operator'=>'OR','fuzziness'=>'AUTO'] ]]
                ]
            ]

],
'sort'=>['_score'=>['order'=>'desc']],
],

'index'=>'products_idx1'
];

 $response = $client->search($params);
echo "<pre>";print_r($response);
```

Comment: do you get results for just "iphone"?

Comment: No i Just give example if someone search like appleiphone so it should return results so for that Should I make search analyzer ?

Comment: @Nate Right now I am getting result zero if I search 'iphone6'

Comment: You need to have tokens that match and b/c ES splits text into tokens on whitespace by default I think that's why you get 0 results with those queries. There are `prefix` queries that might help some of this and you could set up another field variant where all spaces get removed as an alternate analysis. There are a lot of options

Comment: @Nate I do not know correct method for that. If you provide me reference link I can research on that and implement in my project

Comment: [tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) are the thing splitting raw text, the default is called 'standard'

Comment: Elasticsearch won't do a partial match on the substrings of a query.

So, what you are trying to achieve is not optimally possible without changing how you index your data. There are wildcard queries but that might not be optimal for the production search use case. Using **shingles filter** could be one way to achieve this [As explained in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402504/ignore-spaces-in-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [shingle](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) and [pattern_replace token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) it's possible to get the result for all 3 search terms which is mentioned in question and comment aka `iphone`, `iphone6` and `appleiphone` and below is complete example of it.

**As explained in the comment, you search time tokens generated from search term should match the index time tokens generated from indexed doc, in order to get the search result and this is what I've achieved by creating the custom analyzer.**

**Index mapping**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "text_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "shingle",
            "lowercase",
            "space_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "space_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": " ",
          "replacement": "",
          "preserve_original": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "text_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index your sample doc**

```
{
  "title" : "apple iphone 6" 
}
```

**Search query of `appleiphone` with result**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "appleiphone"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ana",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.3439677,
        "_source": {
          "title": "apple iphone 6",
          "title_normal": "apple iphone 6"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search query for `iphone6` with result**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "iphone6"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ana",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.3439677,
        "_source": {
          "title": "apple iphone 6",
          "title_normal": "apple iphone 6"
        }
      }
    ]
```

And Last but not the least search query for `iphone`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "iphone"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ana",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.3439677,
        "_source": {
          "title": "apple iphone 6",
          "title_normal": "apple iphone 6"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but when I search 'iphone6' it still return zero data but if I add new doc 'apple iphone x' and then search by 'iphonex' it returns 'apple iphone x' ,why  it does not search for iphone6 ?

Comment: But I have created a new index and inject new document in that

Comment: @NirajPatel this is strange, You can see in my answer that it works, I've personally tried this locally, hope you have indexed `apple iphone 6` before searching for `iphone6`?

Comment: I accepted your answer and give 50point  and upvote but still I am unable to search iphone6

Comment: I am using elasticsearch 6.8.0 and when I ran your index analyzer code it gave me error so I added one code before "properties"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221359/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-niraj-patel).

Answer (score 1):

As my answer is already very big, adding the information about the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) in another answer for readability reasons and for folks who are not very familiar with analyzers in Elasticsearch and [how it works](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html).

In my previous answer's comment as @Niraj mentioned other documents are working but he is having an issue with `iphone6` query, so in order to debug the issue **anlyze API** is very useful.

First check the index time tokens present for your document which you think should match your search query which is in this case, `apple iphone 6`

PUT http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}/_analyze

```
{
"text" : "apple iphone 6",
"analyzer" : "text_analyzer"
}
```

**And generated tokens**

```
{
"tokens": [
{
"token": "apple",
"start_offset": 0,
"end_offset": 5,
"type": "<ALPHANUM>",
"position": 0
},
{
"token": "appleiphone",
"start_offset": 0,
"end_offset": 12,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 0,
"positionLength": 2
},
{
"token": "iphone",
"start_offset": 6,
"end_offset": 12,
"type": "<ALPHANUM>",
"position": 1
},
{
"token": "iphone6", //note this carefully
"start_offset": 6,
"end_offset": 14,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 1,
"positionLength": 2
},
{
"token": "6",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 14,
"type": "<NUM>",
"position": 2
}
]
}
```

**Now as you can see the analyzer used by us creates `iphone6` also as a token**, now check for search time token

```
{
  "text" : "iphone6",
  "analyzer" : "text_analyzer"
}
```

**And tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "iphone6",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now you can notice search tokens also creats `iphone6` as a token which is present in index time tokens as well, so that's the reason it will match the search query which I already shown in my complete example given in first answer**